# C portable shared library interface: best practice on primitive types

Tags: c, shared-libraries, portability

**Problem:**

Recently we've encountered the following problem with our C shared library. 
The library defines a method like this one:

```
typedef enum {A, B, C} some_enum;
typedef struct {some_enum e; time_t t; char* data;} request;
void f(request);
```

We've compiled the library for multiple architectures using clang and its cross-compilation features. One of the platforms was Windows 32 bits. 
And here is the problem: when trying to use the library in an example that uses MSVC 32-bit compiler, the example fails with seg fault. 
The reason: in MSVC 32-bit `time_t` is 8 bytes while in clang compilation for Windows 32-bits it is assumed to be 4 bytes.

Obviously, if we were using fixed-width integer types such as `int64_t`, this problem would never appear.

**Question:**

Are there established best practices for primitive types in a portable  C shared library?

For instance, is it the best practice to avoid any non fixed-width integer types altogether in C shared library interfaces? 
Are for example `enum`s "allowed" (in terms of best practices) in a portable C library?

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with compiler: you use two incompatible implementations of standard C runtime library (`time.h` to be specific) for compilation of shared library and application code.

Comment: @yugr thanks, it's a very useful observation, I've missed it. I think it is still related to a compiler since I'd expect say a compilation done in Linux Arm 64 architecture to be compatible with the default C runtime library available on this system.

Comment: This is not always the case e.g. different libc implementations on Linux (Glibc, newlib, musl, etc.) are definitely _not_ compatible. As for your case, could you compile the problematic code with `-E` and check which header file provides `time_t`? (for MSVC you can do this same by "opening" `time.h` in Visual Studio editor.

Comment: Note: Windows has `__time64_t` and `__time32_t`. The [`_USE_32BIT_TIME_T` macro determines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/time-time32-time64?view=msvc-170) which one `time_t` is typedefed to.

Comment: Thanks @YakovGalka, good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically all compilers for a given platform try very hard to preserve the default C ABI. Violation of ABI is normally considered a compiler bug.

C++ ABI is trickier for various reasons but at least Clang [tries hard](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html) to preserve that one on Windows as well.

C ABI compatibility means, among other things, that all primitive types have defined size and alignment so there is no need to use fixed-width types (i.e. `long` will be the same for *all* compilers for a particular target).

As for your case, I suspect that clang and cl.exe are using different `time.h` for whatever reason so I suggest to look into that (see my comment above on how to proceed with this).